# Environment with brackets on the left side which is breakable for all nesting depths

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking

I would like to have a breakable environment which indents the content and places a bracket (or at least its corners) on the left side of it, as in the following picture:
[image]

It is crucial that the nested environments are breakable as well, so using tools like `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` is not an option, as they unfortunately do not support breakable nested frames.

I have already tried to do it as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}

\newenvironment{inBrackets}
{
    \begin{adjustwidth}{0.75em}{0pt}
    \vspace{1ex}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=.7pt,lightgray,shift={(-0.625em,0)}]
        \draw ((0,\baselineskip-0.5ex)--(0.625em,\baselineskip-0.5ex);
        \draw ((0,\baselineskip-0.5ex)--(0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{-1em}\vspace{0.5ex}
}
{
    \par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=.7pt,lightgray,shift={(-0.625em,-1.5ex)}]
        \draw ((0,0)--(0,\baselineskip);
        \draw ((0,0)--(0.625em,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{1ex}
    \end{adjustwidth}
}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{This is how it should look like:}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{inBrackets}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{inBrackets}
\lipsum[2]
\end{inBrackets}
\lipsum[2]
\end{inBrackets}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{inBrackets}
\lipsum[2]
\end{inBrackets}
\lipsum[4]

\pagebreak
\paragraph{This unfortunately happens:}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{inBrackets}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{inBrackets}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{inBrackets}
\lipsum[4]
\end{inBrackets}
\end{inBrackets}
\end{inBrackets}

\pagebreak
\paragraph{Instead, I would like it to behave like this:}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{inBrackets}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{inBrackets}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{inBrackets}
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tem-

\pagebreak
pus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.
\end{inBrackets}
\end{inBrackets}
\end{inBrackets}

\end{document}
```

However, whenever a pagebreak happens to be between the ends of several nested environments (marked by lower corners) or between the end of the content inside an environment and its lower corner, then some of the lower corners appear alone on the next side, which looks ugly (see the second example in my MWE).

Instead, I would like the environment to place a pagebreak before the last line of the content inside the environment in such a case (see the third example). Edit: in other words, I want to prevent pages from starting with a closing lower corner, but rather I want them to start with a line of text or an opening lower corner.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: @barbara beeton: Please read the second paragraph of my question: "It is crucial that the nested environments are breakable as well, so using tools like `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` is not an option, as they unfortunately do not support breakable nested frames." The documentation of `mdframed` states explicitly "A nested mdframed environment can’t be splitted."

Comment: you're correct.  i missed that.  i'll remove the comment.  (is it possible to rethink the structure to avoid the nesting?)

Comment: @barbara beeton: No, the nesting is inevitable.

Comment: this is the job of a list environment, may be I will post an answer later to night.

Comment: @touhami: That would be great.

Comment: @emilSmith can you please help me to see the problem?

Comment: @touhami: The problem was that in the second example of my MWE the last two closing lower corners appear alone (without any text) at the top of page 4, whereas I prefer it to look like the third example (from page 5 to 6). In other words, I want to prevent pages from starting with a closing lower corner, but rather I want them to start with a line of text or an opening lower corner.

Comment: @emilSmith ohhh you're right. Thank you. I try to prevent this by using `\@itempenalty\@M` it seems insufficient, i will see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meanwhile, I have found out that adding a simple `\widowpenalties 2 -9999 0` produces the desired behavior. Here is the code for the environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{setspace}

\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}

\newenvironment{inBrackets}
{
    \begin{adjustwidth}{0.75em}{0pt}
    \vspace{1ex}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=.7pt,lightgray,shift={(-0.625em,0)}]
        \draw ((0,\baselineskip-0.5ex)--(0.625em,\baselineskip-0.5ex);
        \draw ((0,\baselineskip-0.5ex)--(0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{-1em}\vspace{0.5ex}
    \widowpenalties 2 -9999 0
}
{
    \par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=.7pt,lightgray,shift={(-0.625em,-1.5ex)}]
        \draw ((0,0)--(0,\baselineskip);
        \draw ((0,0)--(0.625em,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{1ex}
    \end{adjustwidth}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution. the `inBrackets` environment have optional argument (indentation) to be used

```
\begin{inBrackets}[<indent>]
bla bla
\begin{inBrackets}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\bmt}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.7pt,lightgray]
    \draw ((0,\baselineskip-0.5ex)--(0.625em,\baselineskip-0.5ex);
    \draw ((0,\baselineskip-0.5ex)--(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand*{\emt}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.7pt,lightgray]
    \draw ((0,0)--(0,\baselineskip);
    \draw ((0,0)--(0.625em,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{inBrackets}[1][.5cm]
               {\list{}{\leftmargin#1
                        \labelwidth0pt \itemindent0pt \labelsep\leftmargin
                        \def\makelabel##1{\rlap{##1}}}%
               \item[\bmt]}
               {\@itempenalty\@M\item[\emt]\vskip-\baselineskip\endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{inBrackets}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{inBrackets}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{inBrackets}
\lipsum[1]
\end{inBrackets}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, your solution still produces the undesired output described in my question. However, since I have already solved the problem by myself anyway, I just give you an upvote for trying to help me.